# video will not load inline

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I want my video to stream in the view not takeover the screen, ive specified that every way, toggled the option in storyboards and still nothing. any thoughts or ideas, maybe something im missing, please feel free to test the code your self and see the result (fills the entire screen, and still unable to play inline.)

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
    webConfiguration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = []

    LiveStream = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 375, height: 300), configuration: webConfiguration)
    self.view.addSubview(LiveStream)

    if let videoURL:URL = URL(string: "https://devstreaming-cdn.apple.com/videos/streaming/examples/img_bipbop_adv_example_ts/master.m3u8?playsinline=1") {
        let request:URLRequest = URLRequest(url: videoURL)
        LiveStream.load(request)
    }
```

Edited the link to a 24/7 uptime (https://devstreaming-cdn.apple.com/videos/streaming/examples/img_bipbop_adv_example_ts/master.m3u8?playsinline=1)

Comment: @rmaddy how is this not a possible xcode problem (you removed the xcode tag?) am i not understanding the tag sytem correctly?

Comment: Tags represent what the question is about. Your question is not about the Xcode IDE. The fact that you happen to be using Xcode to develop your app is irrelevant to your question. What would be far more useful is to add a tag indicating which OS this is for (iOS or macOS).

Answer (score 1):

I am seeing some mistakes here.

First of all you have already added `WKWebView` in your storyboard and I am guessing that from your

```
@IBOutlet var LiveStream: WKWebView!
```

and you are also adding it into your view again with

```
self.view.addSubview(LiveStream)
```

Which is not correct way to add it.

You can use `UIView` for that.

For that add a `UIView` in your storyboard and create `IBOutlet` for that

```
@IBOutlet weak var viewForEmbeddingWebView: UIView!
```

then declare an instance `var LiveStream: WKWebView!`

Now you can configure `LiveStream` as shown below:

```
let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
webConfiguration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = []

LiveStream = WKWebView(frame: viewForEmbeddingWebView.frame, configuration: webConfiguration)
self.viewForEmbeddingWebView.addSubview(LiveStream)

if let videoURL:URL = URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/9n1e1N0Sa9k?playsinline=1") {
    let request:URLRequest = URLRequest(url: videoURL)
    LiveStream.load(request)
}
```

And your result will be:

[image]

As you have noticed video is playing inside the `WKWebView` not in full screen.

**Note:**

Your `URL` wasn't working for me so I have used another `URL` for demonstrate.

Comment: yes i did realize i was declaring that twice myself as well. this method seems to work with youtube videos but not with a .m3u8 link as it pays no attention to the inline policy. @Dharmesh i have also restarted the test stream so it should work now

Comment: try this link if it goes offline it produces the same flawed result: https://devstreaming-cdn.apple.com/videos/streaming/examples/img_bipbop_adv_example_ts/master.m3u8?playsinline=1 @Dharmesh