# How to control AVPlayer subview in storyboards without breaking function

Tags: ios, avplayer

this is my current code:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var videoView: UIView!
var player: AVPlayer!
var avpController = AVPlayerViewController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let url = URL(string:"https://devstreaming-cdn.apple.com/videos/streaming/examples/img_bipbop_adv_example_ts/master.m3u8")

    player = AVPlayer(url: url!)

    avpController.player = player

    avpController.view.frame.size.height = videoView.frame.size.height

    avpController.view.frame.size.width = videoView.frame.size.width

    self.videoView.addSubview(avpController.view)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Story board:

[image: Storyboard]

the results =

[image: ios]

im aiming for it to fill the entire view in the future i plan to add the ability to swipe down to minimize and browse the app while watching the live stream.

currently im unable to make the view in storyboards have controll of the subview. is it possible to do this or am i better off writing it in code? my only concern is when the user is using other devices other then an X then.

Comment: You should probably use AVPlayerLayer over AVPlayerViewController, this way you can customise it the actual video layer, you just set the frame to the bounds of the video container view

Comment: the problem with that is videos will not load inline @SeanLintern88

Comment: Why would they not load inline, your just making a different layer to view it in, its up to you when to press play ...

Comment: this may answer your question @SeanLintern88. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55056853/video-will-not-load-inline

Comment: No, this doesnt have anything to do with what I mentioned.

Comment: Then i dont know how to anwser your question @SeanLintern88 as it is imposible to load inline in any other way then this (to my knowege)

Comment: I think your confusing things tbh, they are just 2 ways of showing video players. AVPlayerViewController is intended for full screen playback AFAIK, AVPlayerLayer is for custom solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so this is a minor technical problem... it turnsout even though i specified a width becuase i have not added side contraints it did not exstend to the sides... it's odd though a 375 width should have covered the scree with out the exstra contraints.